# Escape String interpolation in a string literal

Tags: kotlin, string-literals, string-interpolation

In a normal String I can escape the `${variable}` with a backslash:

```
"You can use \${variable} syntax in Kotlin."
```

Is it possible to do the same in a String literal? The backslash is no longer an escape character:

```
// Undesired: Produces "This \something will be substituted.
"""This \${variable} will be substituted."""
```

So far, the only solutions I see are String concatenation, which is terribly ugly, and nesting the interpolation, which starts to get a bit ridiculous:

```
// Desired: Produces "This ${variable} will not be substituted."
"""This ${"\${variable}"} will not be substituted."""
```

Comment: When you have such a question (no matter the language) I suggest you use something like https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: Can you explain what "such a question" means?

Comment: Sure, I mean something that can be tested/reproduced in a second or two :)

Comment: What is the exact desired output? Is it `"This \something will be substituted."` or `"This ${variable} will not be substituted."`?

Comment: @deHaar the latter.

Comment: a simple solution can be to add a `whitespace`  between `$` and `{`.. it won't hurt the format as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates):

*If you need to represent a literal $ character in a raw string (which doesn't 
support backslash escaping), you can use the following syntax:*

```
val price = """
${'$'}9.99
"""
```

So, in your case:

```
"""This ${'$'}{variable} will not be substituted."""
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [String templates docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) you can represent the `$` directly in a raw string:

> Templates are supported both inside raw strings and inside escaped strings. If you need to represent a literal $ character in a raw string (which doesn't support backslash escaping), you can use the following syntax:

```
val text = """This ${'$'}{variable} will be substituted."""
println(text) // This ${variable} will be substituted.
```